# How to handle limited photo library in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

When a IOS user selects the limited access option when granting permissions to their photo library, how do I check if the image they chose in expo-image-picker is a photo they've granted access to the app?

```
  const pickImage = async () => {
    const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    console.log(status)
    if (status === 'granted') {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: true,
        quality: 1,
        allowsMultipleSelection: false,
      });
      setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
    } else {
      // Permission denied
      // Handle the denial or show an error message to the user
      Alert.alert(
        'Permission denied',
        'Photo Gallery permission is needed to be able to analyze text in photos. Please go to settings to grant permission'
      );
    }
  };
```

I expect the app to tell the user if they have given access to the photo they select in my app, but I can't find any resources on how to check if the user has danied access to a photo they have chosen.